# Comparar caracteres dentro de un array en java

Tags: java

Necesito hacer un programa el cual compare dos cadenas, las pase a caracter y si estas NO son iguales me diga en que posición del caracter esta el error, hasta ahora llevo esto pero no logro realizarlo

```
public class LimitarCaracter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] caracteresp;
        char[] caracterese;
        String predeterminada = "";
        String entrada = "";
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra definida");
        predeterminada = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra a evaluar");
        entrada = leer.nextLine();
        caracteresp = predeterminada.toCharArray();
        caracterese = entrada.toCharArray();
        for (int x = 0; x < caracteresp.length; x++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < caracterese.length; i++) {
                if (caracteresp[x] == caracterese[i]) {
                    System.out.println("La cadena es igual");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("La cadena no es igual");
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te dejo el código explicado y probado. Si tienes alguna duda me avisas.

```
char[] caracteresp, caracterese;
String predeterminada, entrada;
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra definida");
predeterminada = leer.nextLine();
System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra a evaluar");
entrada = leer.nextLine();
caracteresp = predeterminada.toCharArray();
caracterese = entrada.toCharArray();

int tamaño;
if(caracterese.length < caracteresp.length) //comparamos cuál de los 2 es el arreglo más largo para poder comparar en base a él.
    tamaño = caracteresp.length;
else
    tamaño = caracterese.length;

int ultima_posicion = 0; //lo usaremos en el caso que una cadena sea más larga que la otra
try
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++)
    {
        ultima_posicion = i; //guardamos la última posición en el caso que una cadena sea más larga que la otra
        if(caracteresp[i] != caracterese[i]) //comparamos ambas cadenas y le pedimos la misma posición para saber si son iguales
        {
            //Si no son iguales mostramos la posición e imprimimos el caracter que no coincide
            System.err.println("Caracter en la posición [" + i + "]: '" + caracterese[i] + "' no coincide con el original: '" + caracteresp[i] + "'");
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Cadena ok");
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
    //Si la cadena a evaluar es menor a la original entonces mostrar error que no se encontró caracter
    if(caracterese.length < caracteresp.length)
        System.err.println("No se encontró caracter en la posición [" + ultima_posicion + "], se esperaba: '" + caracteresp[ultima_posicion] + "'");
    //Si la cadena a evaluar es mayor a la original entonces mostrar que la cadena evaluada excedió rango original
    else
        System.err.println("Caracter en la posición [" + ultima_posicion + "]: " + caracterese[ultima_posicion] + " (Excedió rango original)");
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Recuerda, como buena práctica de programación, que el manejo de excepciones debe reducirse a los elementos que realmente no puedes controlar como programador. La longitud de una cadena siempre se puede controlar (antes de la llamada como precondición, o durante la ejecución del código dentro del método). Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia, lo tendré muy encuentra. :)

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, este fue el que se ajustaba a lo que se me pedia un saludo :D

Answer (score 0):

Aquí un ejemplo donde compara las palabras:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] caracteresp;
        char[] caracterese;
        String predeterminada = "";
        String entrada = "";
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra definida");
        predeterminada = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra a evaluar");
        entrada = leer.nextLine();
        caracteresp = predeterminada.toCharArray();
        caracterese = entrada.toCharArray();

        int longitudMenor = caracteresp.length < caracterese.length ? caracteresp.length
                : caracterese.length;
        int longitudMayor = caracteresp.length > caracterese.length ? caracteresp.length
                : caracterese.length;

        // MUESTRA UN MENSAJE CUANDO LAS PALBRAS SON DE DIFERENTES LONGITUDES
        if (longitudMenor != longitudMayor) {
            System.out.println("Las cadena no son iguales");
        }

        // COMPARA LETRA CON LETRA, SI NO SON IGUALES DEJA DE COMPARAR
        for (int x = 0; x < longitudMayor; x++) {
            if (longitudMenor > x)
                if (caracteresp[x] == caracterese[x]) {
                    System.out.println("La cadena: " + caracteresp[x]
                            + "  es igual a : " + caracterese[x]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("La cadena: " + caracteresp[x]
                            + "  no es igual a : " + caracterese[x]);
                    break;
                }
        }

    }
```

se hizo un ejemplo con las palabras **"hola"** y **"hoga"** y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
La cadena: h  es igual a : h
La cadena: o  es igual a : o
La cadena: l  no es igual a : g
```

Aquí te muestra que caracteres no son iguales

Comment: Muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta amigo, sin embargo aun estoy comenzando en la programacion y desconozco lo que hace el simbolo "?" y el ":" si me pudieras explicar estaria de lujo, muchisimas gracias :D

Comment: Que tal esa línea de código es equivalente a un if else común y corriente, aquí un pequeño ejemplo de como utilizarlo http://lineadecodigo.com/java/el-operador-ternario-en-java/ y https://serprogramador.es/utilizando-un-if-con-operador-ternario/